# DocuSign Connect / eventNotification event parser / contract

Tags: .net, rest, docusignapi

I successfully received an event from DocuSign. I can process it by parsing the XML and deserializing it to an object.

I created a class for this xml from Paste Special => Paste XML as a Classes.

Is there any complete definition of this event?

Any contract or ready for use class in docusign-csharp-client?

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation for the DocuSign Connect/eventNotification XML events.](https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/connect-guide_0.pdf)

There is no parsing class available from DocuSign as of this writing.

If you'd like to open source your work, that would be much appreciated. You can store it on GitHub and then add an issue to the DocuSign C# SDK repo to let DocuSign know about your library. Please remember to declare an open source license for your work, eg the MIT or Apache licenses.